# How to set proxy for Chromium on Windows with Playwright Java?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I'm trying to use a proxy for Chromium on Windows:

```
BrowserType.LaunchOptions launchOptions = new BrowserType.LaunchOptions();
launchOptions.setProxy(new Proxy("localhost:8888"));

Browser browser = Playwright.create().chromium().launch(launchOptions);
```

In the settings I see that the proxy has been set properly, but the option `Use proxyserver` is set to `false`.

[image: Windows' proxy settings]

How to change that?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Setting the Proxy in Playwright does not depend on any OS settings. I'd recommend you to file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @MaxSchmitt, a bug in Playwright? 
For Chrome on Windows it's usual that it's using the OS' proxy settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `--proxy-server` command line switch:

```java
launchOptions.setArgs(List.of("--proxy-server=http://localhost:8888"))
```

([via](https://scrapingant.com/blog/how-to-use-a-proxy-in-playwright))

Answer (score 2):

I tested this with version 1.22.0 and it works:

```
package test;

import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserType;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright;
import com.microsoft.playwright.options.Proxy;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
      BrowserType.LaunchOptions launchOptions = new BrowserType.LaunchOptions();
      launchOptions.headless = false;
      launchOptions.setProxy(new Proxy("localhost:8888"));
      Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(launchOptions);
      Page page = browser.newPage();
      page.navigate("http://playwright.dev");
      System.out.println(page.title());
    }
  }
}
```

The launchOptions don't cause the system proxy setting to be set. Values on your screenshot must have been entered before.

Comment: This is basically what I tried, and is not working for me.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann, sorry, I edited the answer a few times because of confusion created by Fiddler setting the OS proxy settings.